# python .rstrip removes one additional character

Tags: python

I try to remove seconds from date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> test1 = datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 10, 0, 0)
>>> test1
datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 10, 0, 0)
>>> str(test1)
'2011-06-10 00:00:00'
>>> str(test1).rstrip('00:00:00')
'2011-06-10 '
>>> str(test1).rstrip(' 00:00:00')
'2011-06-1'
```

Why 0 at end of '10' is removed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`str.rstrip()` doesn't remove an exact string -- it removes all characters that occur in the string.  Since you know the length of the string to remove, you can simply use

```
str(test1)[:-9]
```

or even better

```
test1.date().isoformat()
```

Comment: Right. `>>> str(test1).rstrip('0:')
'2011-06-10 '
>>> str(test1).rstrip(' 0:')
'2011-06-1'`

Answer (score 7):

`rstrip` takes a set (although the argument can be any iterable, like `str` in your example) of characters that are removed, not a single string.

And by the way, the string representation of `datetime.datetime` is not fixed, you can't rely on it. Instead, use [`isoformat`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) on the [date](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) or [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> test1 = datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 10, 0, 0)
>>> test1.date().isoformat()
'2011-06-10'
>>> test1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2011-06-10'
```