# Bug in rstrip or what?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python .rstrip removes one additional character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311968/python-rstrip-removes-one-additional-character)

What is the problem here? it seems that rstrip removes more than necessary in the one to the last line of code.

```
s = 'LedArray.py'
s.rstrip('y')
'LedArray.p'

s.rstrip('py')
'LedArray.'

s.rstrip('.py')
'LedArra'

s.rstrip('y.py')
'LedArra'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rstrip` takes "characters to remove", not "exact substring to remove" argument. `.py` and `y.py` are equivalent as sets. In fact, you could do `y.p` and it'd still remove the same characters.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the second argument to `rstrip()` is a *set* of characters, not a sequence. The characters to be removed do *not* need to occur in the order given.

This also means that `rstrip('y.py')` is exactly the same as `rstrip('.py')`, a character can't be in the set twice.