# Weird string stripping

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python .rstrip removes one additional character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311968/python-rstrip-removes-one-additional-character)

i have a string `vtype` defined as

```
vtype = "vidis.fit"
```

i want to strip the final `dis.fit` away, so

```
vtype.rstrip("dis.fit")
```

but the end result is `v`, rather than `vi`, the one I expected/wanted. I'm a bit confused about this, anyone?

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone. I guess the reason why it confused me in the first place is that, the naming of `lstrip` and `rstrip` seems suggesting some sequence, although it only matters to white spaces.

Comment: @Marcin he tried `rstrip` and got `v`, I'm not sure what's unclear about his question

Comment: @Marcin: Are you just parroting that at random? The sscce is right in the question.

Comment: @Marcin I love your comment, useless and boring. What else should I try?

Comment: @interjay Right? He didn't even read the documentation for the function he's using. Asking a question on SO should not be the very first resort.

Comment: @Marcin whatever you said, RTFM has nothing to do with SSCCE.

Comment: @nye17 Both of those links are relevant to "how to ask a good question". Is that a problem for you?

Comment: @Marcin Hehe, if every user reads and understands the doc, and every developer writes clear doc, what's the point of stackoverflow and your salient online image here?

Comment: @nye17 It's possible for people to read and not understand.

Comment: @Marcin True. In any case, I'm glad that I never asked a question plagued with negative votes on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rstrip` actually [takes a sequence of characters at the end of a string to strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), not a specific string to strip.  It's removing the `i` because `i` is in the sequence of characters passed in.

For example, the order of characters in `rstrip` doesn't matter:

```
>>> vtype = "vidis.fit"
>>> vtype.rstrip("dis.fit")
'v'
>>> vtype.rstrip("ditfs.")
'v'
```

Nor does the number of times a character is in it:

```
>>> vtype.rstrip("ditffffsssss.")
'v'
```

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) specify:

> The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its
>   values are stripped

**EDIT:**  And for fun, if you really want to solve the "how do I remove a string at the end of a string" problem, use `rfind` with slicing:

```
>>> vtype[:vtype.rfind("dis.fit")]
'vi'
```

Comment: I see. the docstring doesn't seem quite clear to me on the distinction between `characters` and `sequence of characters`. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, the docstring in my local copy doesnt have your above portion, hell!

Comment: @nye17: The docstring is not the documentation.  It's a short summary of the documentation provided for convenience.  If in doubt, check the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The "i" after "v" is removed because it's a character in 'dis.fit'. The argument to `strip` isn't a substring to remove, but a list of chars to remove.

Answer (score 1):

as indicated in the other answers, rstrip takes a sequence of chars to remove, not a particular string.

```
"vidis.fit".replace("dis.fit", "")
```

will actually do what you're looking to do... unless the "dis.fit" sequence may appear more than once, or in a different position. In which case you can probably work out some regex solution.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm using now.